# SQL GROUP BY FirstName, Lastname and Year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have made the query below=>

```
SELECT FirstName,
       LastName,
       COUNT(*) AantalBestellingen,
       YEAR(Orders.OrderDate) as Jaar
from Employees 
    RIGHT JOIN Orders ON (Employees.EmployeeID=Orders.EmployeeID) 
WHERE Employees.ReportsTo IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY Employees.FirstName, Employees.LastName, YEAR (Orders.OrderDate)
ORDER BY YEAR (Orders.OrderDate)
```

I need to select the first name, lastname from the employees and the total orders they have processed within the last year.

After adding the group by year to the query it's not showing the unique employees anymore but it shows the years. I need to get only the unique employees and the last order year they have processed an order in.

Any advice what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's the purpose with RIGHT JOIN combined with "WHERE Employees.ReportsTo IS NOT NULL"? Doesn't that make it a regular INNER JOIN?!?

Comment: You say 1) "I need to select the first name, lastname from the employees and the total orders they have processed within the last year", and 2) "I need to get only the unique employees and the last order year they have processed an order in." This is two different queries, which one do you want?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with an inner select:

```
SELECT 
  FirstName, 
  LastName, 
  COUNT(*) as AantalBestellingen, 
  (select YEAR(max(Orders.OrderDate)) from Orders O 
      where Employees.EmployeeID=O.EmployeeID) as Jaar 
from 
  Employees 
  RIGHT JOIN Orders 
    ON (Employees.EmployeeID=Orders.EmployeeID) 
  WHERE 
    Employees.ReportsTo IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY 
  Employees.FirstName, 
  Employees.LastName
ORDER BY Jaar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place the Last Year condition in WHERE clause as follows

```
SELECT FirstName,
       LastName,
       COUNT(*) AantalBestellingen,
from Employees 
    RIGHT JOIN Orders ON (Employees.EmployeeID=Orders.EmployeeID) 
WHERE Employees.ReportsTo IS NOT NULL AND YEAR(Orders.OrderDate) = 2014
GROUP BY Employees.FirstName, Employees.LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one... This will give all employee, his only last year order count and last year.

```
;with cteMaxYear as
(select max(YEAR(Orders.OrderDate)) MaxOrderYear, EmployeeID 
from Orders 
group by EmployeeID)

SELECT FirstName,
       LastName,
       COUNT(*) AantalBestellingen,
       m.MaxOrderYear as Jaar
from Employees e
left outer join cteMaxYear m
    inner join Orders o ON m.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID and m.MaxOrderYear=o.YEAR(Orders.OrderDate)
    on e.EmployeeID = m.EmployeeID
WHERE e.ReportsTo IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY e.FirstName, e.LastName, m.MaxOrderYear
ORDER BY  m.MaxOrderYear
```